# Proving $|\cos(x)| \geq 1 − \sin^2(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

The question says:

> Prove that the inequality $|\cos(x)| \geq 1 − \sin^2(x)$ holds true for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Now I tried to prove it using induction. I want someone to check it and let me know if this method is fine.
My attempt is given below.

For $x = 1$, we have

$|\cos(1)| ≥ 1 − \sin^2(1)$

which is true.

Let us assume that this inequality is true for $x = k$.
Then let us check it for $x = k + 1$.

$|\cos(k+1)| ≥ 1 − \sin^2(k+1)$

Take square on both sides.

$\cos^2(k+1) ≥ 1 − 2\sin^2(k+1) + \sin^4(k+1)$

Divide both sides by $\sin^2(k+1)$, we get

$\cot^2(k+1) ≥ \csc^2(k+1)− 2 + \sin^2(k+1)$

$\cot^2(k+1) - \csc^2(k+1) ≥ − 2 + \sin^2(k+1)$

$ -1 +2 ≥ \sin^2(k+1)$

$ 1 ≥ \sin^2(k+1)$

which is true. Thus, the inequality is true.

Comment: Hint: $1 - \sin^2(x) = \cos^2(x)$

Comment: You cannot use induction on $x$ since takes values from all real numbers.

Comment: Even if your proof is correct, it only addresses the case where $x$ is a positive integer.  You need to prove the statement for all real values of $x$.

Comment: Induction is something you can use when natural numbers are involved, not on real numbers.

Comment: That's true, @amWhy, but why ?

Comment: got it guys. Thanks. I did not keep know that we can use induction for integers only.

Comment: @jed just want to note that your proof for case $x = k+1$ does not use assumption made for $x = k$. So actually your proof doesn't use induction and may be applied to any real number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since
$|\cos(x)| \le 1,
0 \le \cos^2(x)\le  |\cos(x)| \le 1
$.

Therefore
$|\cos(x)|
\ge \cos^2(x)
=1 - \sin^2(x)
$.

Comment: (+1) All too easy.

Answer (score 0):

Using,  $-1\leq \cos x\leq 1$

$|\cos(x)| ≥ 1 − \sin^2(x)=\sin^2x+\cos^2x-\sin^2x=\cos^2x$

Or

In short

$|\cos(x)| ≥ 1 − \sin^2(x)=\cos^2x$

And it is obvious that if $-1\leq x\leq1$,  then,   $|x| ≥ x^2$

Comment: please use `\trig-function` when formatting in mathjax.  E.g. `\cos, \sin`

Comment: @amWhy :  noted, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since $1-\sin^2x=\cos^2x$, it is equivalent to
$$\forall\,a\in[0,1] \enspace a^2\le a.$$